# Difference between the result of two date fields then getting average

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am looking to get the average of the difference between two different fields in an elastic DB, I have been able to write a query to return the last 1000 results, however I am not sure how I go about getting the difference between each result then getting an overall average.

Elastic query below:

```
POST my_index/_search
{
  "size":1000,
  "_source": ["date.time.received","date.time.sent"],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "date.time.received": {
              "gte": "2019-06-19"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "date.time.sent": {
              "gte": "2019-06-19"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using average aggregation and script

```
POST testindex5/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "date.time.received": {
              "gte": "2019-06-19"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "date.time.sent": {
              "gte": "2019-06-19"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "avg_resp": {
      "avg": {
        "script": "(doc['date.time.received'].value.toInstant().toEpochMilli()- doc['date.time.sent'].value.toInstant().toEpochMilli())/1000/86400"  ---> convert to days
      }
    }
  }
}
```